# Beginning JavaScript question using the Eclipse IDE

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse

I'm a beginner at JavaScript so go easy on me here. (This is not supposed to be Java. I know they're different)

So I'm trying to run my first script in the Eclipse IDE and the code is just:
`document.write("<h1>Hello World<h1>");`

But my console says:

```
<terminated> js Proj 2-ffirst.js [Node Application] Node.js Process
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Javascript\js Proj 2\ffirst.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

I suspect my issue is in how I set up the software but I haven't learned how to use this yet really so I'm open to any suggestions you have. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are running your script in node. Instead of `document.write` try `console.log`. `document.write` is only available in dom environments(browsers ect).

Comment: I suggest you to install nodejs(if not already) and run "node script.js" to see errors better. Seems like eclipse is hijacking the error message. You should get something like this: ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal I suggest to stop making such comments that recommend your favorite tool. [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) uses/embeds the VS Code TypeScript/JavaScript language server which means switching between Eclipse and VS Code will change the UI but not the JavaScript language support (same code completion proposals, etc.).

Comment: @howlger I actually did not know that. Thanks. will not suggest tools from now ✌!

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal Thanks. By the way, with Java it is the other way round, [in VS Code the Java language support is a headless Eclipse as language server](https://twitter.com/howlger/status/1358189525424459777).

Answer (score 0):

you are running a node app - as node is on the server it doesn't know what the document and window are (they are browser api's only accessible on the client side)

Because they don't know what the document Object is you get an error.

Try either console.log to print a response in the terminal from your node server or move to something like VS code to write a plain .js file that can be launched through the browser.

Comment: [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) uses/embeds the VS Code TypeScript/JavaScript language server and also supports to run or debug a .js file as Node.js application or in a web browser.